# Find if line in inputted text file is all uppercase or not, java

Tags: java

I have an inputted text file that contains lines of text. Some lines are all uppercase while other lines are both uppercase and lowercase. I am trying to figure out how to single out just the all uppercase, capitalized text lines from the non-capitalized lines. I tried `Character.isUpperCase()` but that doesn't work because the text is not Characters. Any ideas?

So basically I need to do something like "if uppercase, do this, else do that" and I can't figure out the "if uppercase" part.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.toUpperCase()` along with `equals()`:

```
String line1 = "THIS LINE IS ALL CAPS";
String line2 = "THIS line is MIXED";

if (line1.equals(line1.toUpperCase())) {
    System.out.println("Line 1 is all uppercase.");
}

if (line2.equals(line2.toUpperCase())) {
    System.out.println("Line 2 is all uppercase.");
}
```

**Output:**

```
Line 1 is all uppercase.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert input string to all upperCase and store it on New variable(say `inputUppercase`)
And then simply check if `inputUppercase` and input are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use regex:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z. ]+$"); //regex that matches uppercase and space and period only
 for(String line : lines){
     Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
     if(m.matches()){ // all upper case
          ... 
     }
 }
```

[Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)